# SBT doesn't use a resolver?

Tags: sbt

I use SBT **0.13.1**.

I have the following `resolvers` in `plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
```

and the following lib dependency:

```
"org.squeryl" % "squeryl2_10" % "0.9.6-SNAPSHOT"
```

SBT does not seem to use the snapshot resolver as I can see that the artifact is present in http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/squeryl/squeryl_2.10/0.9.6-SNAPSHOT/.

```
[warn]  module not found: org.squeryl#squeryl2_10;0.9.6-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/max/.ivy2/local/org.squeryl/squeryl2_10/0.9.6-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/squeryl/squeryl2_10/0.9.6-SNAPSHOT/squeryl2_10-0.9.6-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/squeryl/squeryl2_10/0.9.6-SNAPSHOT/squeryl2_10-0.9.6-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.squeryl#squeryl2_10;0.9.6-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have added the resolvers to `plugins.sbt` in the `project` subdirectory, but the Squeryl is not a plugin or a dependency of one and should really be added to an `.sbt` file in your project's main directory. It's usually `build.sbt`.